# ListIterator how to code nextIndex() and previousIndex()

Tags: java

For a course, I'm having to write code for a List class, which involves writing parts of a ListIterator and using a ListIteratorAPI (NOT from java.util)

I'm having trouble writing nextIndex and previousIndex

Below is the ListIterator class

```
private class ListIterator implements ListIteratorAPI<E> {

    /**
     * current cursor position
     */
    private Node position;

    /**
     * previous cursor position
     */
    private Node previous;

    /**
     * Constructs an iterator that points to the front of the linked list.
     */
    public ListIterator() {
        position = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    @Override
    public E next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
            throw new ListException("Called at the end of the list");
        }
        previous = position;
        if (position == null) {
            position = first;
        } else {
            position = position.next;
        }
        return position.data;
    }

    @Override
    public E previous() {
        if (!hasPrevious()) {
            throw new ListException("Called at the beginning of the list");
        }
        previous = position;
        if (position == null) {
            position = last;
        } else {
            position = position.previous;
        }
        return position.data;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (position == null) {
            return first != null;
        } else {
            return position.next != null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPrevious() {
        if (position == null) {
            return last != null;
        } else {
            return position.previous != null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(E element) {
        if (position == null) {
            addFirst(element);
            position = first;
        } else {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = position.next;
            if (newNode.next != null) {
                newNode.next.previous = newNode;
            }
            position.next = newNode;
            newNode.previous = position;
            position = newNode;
            if (newNode.previous == last) {
                last = newNode;
            }
            size++;
        }
        previous = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if (previous == position) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        if (position == first) {
            removeFirst();
        } else {
            Node tmp = position;
            previous.next = position.next;
            if (position.next != null) {
                position.next.previous = previous;
            }
            tmp.next = tmp.previous = null;
            size--;
        }
        position = previous;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(E element) {
        if (position == null) {
            throw new ListException("set calls on a null node");
        }
        position.data = element;
    }

    @Override
    public int nextIndex() {

    }

    @Override
    public int previousIndex() {

    }
}
```

Here is the ListIteratorAPI I'm using

```
    public interface ListIteratorAPI <E>
{
    /**
     * returns true if next() method returns an element rather than an exception
     * @return true if list has more elements when moving the list in the forward
     * direction
     */
    public boolean hasNext();

    /**
 * returns true if previous() method returns an element rather than an exception
 * @return true if list has more elements when moving the list in the reverse
 * direction
 */
public boolean hasPrevious();

/**
 * returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position
 * @returnthe next element
 * @throws ListException if the iteration has no next element
 */
public E next() throws ListException;

/**
 * returns the index of the element that would be returned by a subsequent
 * call to next() method
 * @return the index of the element or list size if the iterator is at the
 * end of the list
 */
public int nextIndex();

/**
 * returns the previous element in the list and moves the cursor position
 * backwards
 * @return the previous element
 * @throws ListException if the iteration has no previous element 
 */
public E previous() throws ListException;

/**
 * returns the index of the element that would be returned by a subsequent
 * call to previous() method
 *
 * @return the index of the element or -1 if the iterator is at the
 * beginning of the list.
 */
public int previousIndex();

/**
 * Adds an element before the iterator position and moves the iterator past
 * the inserted element.
 *
 * @param element the element to add
 */
void add(E element);

/**
 * Removes the last traversed element. This method may only be called after
 * a call to the next() method.
 */
void remove();

/**
 * Replaces the last element returned by next() or previous() with the
 * specified element.
 *
     * @param element the element to set
     */
    void set(E element);
   }
```

Comment: You could keep an `int` to store the current index. Starts at '0', increment/decrement as you run along.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a good place to put it, using the code above?

Comment: add `private int index;` after your other two fields.